# FlexMDI & RobotLegs: How to use multiple context, that can run independentely and sometimes shares the same view?

Tags: apache-flex

Hy!

What I really need is to make a mainContext and within add other contexts that are kind of other applications. The main context has a MDICanvas where all the windows are added, but the problem is that some windows comes from different context. The next problem is that I want that windowX only listens to contextX:

Example:
 mainContext
  ->open login window
    ->open register window
  ->open register window
  taskmanagerContext
   servicesContext
    ->open add new service window
  worldEngineContext